# Update of panel title in sencha touch does work on android but not on ios

Tags: android, ios, sencha-touch-2

I am developing a html5 website with Sencha Touch 2.3.1.
It is an mvc based app created with Sencha Cmd, but mixed with a VB.net webproject.

I have defined a tab panel, with several sub panels in a view.
After creating the view I want the controller to change the text of most elements in the view (multilanguage).
I retrieve the text in the controller, by calling a webservice, and fill an array with the result of the jsonp call:

```
launch: function () {
    var me = this;
    var updateurl = mainsource + 'TheUserInterface/GetSiteText?lanid=' + LanId + '&accesskey=' + accesskey;
    Ext.data.JsonP.request({
        url: updateurl,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result != '') {
                var nrels = result.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < nrels; i++) {
                    var Key = result[i].Key
                    var Val = result[i].Value
                    SiteText[Key] = Val;
                };
                var tabpanel = me.getMain().items.items[1].items.items[0];
                tabpanel.tab.setHtml(SiteText['welcome']);
                tabpanel.items.items[1].update(SiteText['title1']);
                me.getMain().items.items[0].items.items[2].setHtml(SiteText['logon']);
            }
            else {
                SiteText = '';
            }
        }
    })
}
```

This works perfectly fine on my laptop in Chrome, Firefox, but not in Safari and IE (the latter is not relevant for me.
It also works perfectly fine on an Android mobile phone, but not on an iPhone 4 or iPhone 5 or an iPad.
It seems that iOS does not give me access to the dom-elements.
I have tried it also using Ext.getCmp(), but that also did not work.

Does any one of you have the golden answer for me?

KR

Henk Jelt Hoving

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.

It had nothing to do with not accessing DOM elements in iOS.
I found a way to monitor my iPhone traffic with Fiddler2 on my laptop, and it appears that iOS is very strict about files to be present.
I have defined a favicon, which I forgot to copy to my test-server, and iOS did not like that.
It stopped halfway the process.
After copying the ico file to the test server my mobile test also works on iOS, both in Chrome and Safari.

Henk Jelt